# What is the difference between @EnableWebSecurity and @EnableWebFluxSecurity?

Tags: spring-security, spring-webflux, spring-security-oauth2, spring-cloud-gateway

What is the difference between `@EnableWebSecurity` and `@EnableWebFluxSecurity` from the context of security?

I am trying to use a Spring Cloud Gateway which supports few reactive Micro-services in the downstream. And few normal web services as well. And wanted to user `@EnableWebSecuirty` in the API Gateway. So will that work with reactive Services as well?

Answer (score 4):

They both have same security semantics, but `@EnableWebSecurity` is used in a MVC stack whereas `@EnableWebFluxSecurity` is used in the reactive stack (enabling Spring Security WebFlux).